# NativeScript system icons

Tags: nativescript

Where can I find system icons for `nativescript`?

for example:

```
<ActionBar title="ActionBar Style">
    <NavigationButton text="Go Back" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back"></NavigationButton>
    <ActionItem ios.systemIcon="2" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_edit" ios.position="right"></ActionItem>
</ActionBar>
```

Where can I find 
`ic_menu_back`, `ic_menu_edit`  icons?

Comment: can you accept the answer if it solved your problem? :)

Answer (score 3):

You can find all the system icons here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html

Anyway read also this:

http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/action-bar.html#setting-icons

Comment: How do we know how any one of these icons looks like without using it in the app and compiling it and then seeing it?

Answer (score -2):

They're also included with Android Studio, which you probably have installed already. I hacked this .bat file out to copy an icon to my app folder on Windows:

```
@echo on
set BAT_FILE=%~n0
set source="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\layoutlib\data\res"
set target=".\App_Resources\Android"
set f1=drawable-hdpi
set f2=drawable-ldpi
set f3=drawable-mdpi
set f4=drawable-nodpi
set f5=drawable-xhdpi
set f6=drawable-xxhdpi
set f7=drawable-xxxhdpi

set icon=ic_menu_back.png

if exist %source%\%f1%\%icon% copy %source%\%f1%\%icon% %target%\%f1%\ >%BAT_FILE%.txt 
if exist %source%\%f2%\%icon% copy %source%\%f2%\%icon% %target%\%f2%\ >>%BAT_FILE%.txt 
if exist %source%\%f3%\%icon% copy %source%\%f3%\%icon% %target%\%f3%\ >>%BAT_FILE%.txt 
if exist %source%\%f4%\%icon% copy %source%\%f4%\%icon% %target%\%f4%\ >>%BAT_FILE%.txt 
if exist %source%\%f5%\%icon% copy %source%\%f5%\%icon% %target%\%f5%\ >>%BAT_FILE%.txt 
if exist %source%\%f6%\%icon% copy %source%\%f6%\%icon% %target%\%f6%\ >>%BAT_FILE%.txt 
if exist %source%\%f7%\%icon% copy %source%\%f7%\%icon% %target%\%f7%\ >>%BAT_FILE%.txt 

type %BAT_FILE%.txt 
rem .
pause
erase %BAT_FILE%.txt
```

Hope this helps.